# Saving an AspNetUser from an Azure AD Bearer token with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I am writing an Angular SPA front-end with DotNet Core 2.2 API-only backend using Azure Active Directory for authentication (e.g. via [Azure AD OAuth 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview) `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<app-id>&redirect_uri=<callback>&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile`). The SPA authenticates with Azure AD and receives a JWT id_token which is also used when calling the DotNet Core backend via the Authorization Bearer HTTP header. It is validated by the backend with the `[Authorize]` attribute on controllers.

I can read the JWT user claims just fine on controller endpoints; however, I would like to be able to store the basic details about the authenticated user into the `AspNetUsers` table provided by ASP.NET Identity for correlating records to an authenticated user at the data layer (perhaps by the [`UserManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?).

**Where would be the best place to add the validated Azure AD JWT user information to the ASP.NET Identity tables?**

Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(config => { config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
    ...
}
```

SampleDataController.cs

```cs
[Authorize(Roles="employee")]
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts()
{
    var userEmail = User.Identity.Name; // e.g. david.yee@myworkemail.com
    ...
}
```

Comment: First Option:- You can have an intermediate action method which will be responsible for doing validation and if succeed than you can store the JWT information in DB tables. Second Option-Alternatively you can have a filter created for doing validation and storing JWT information to ASP.Net tables.You can decorate this filter on top of  controller so for every single request you JWT will be validated. you can customize as per your need. you candecorate it above action method or whole controller.Let me know if you need any help related to filter creation.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT Thank you for that description. In option 1 is that referring to, for example, a controller endpoint that is called by the SPA (with the JWT) after successful auth with Azure AD? Option 2 makes sense to me but would it be expensive to be checking the JWT token against the user database (e.g. if it doesn't exist, create the record) for every single request?

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT If I understand option 1 correctly, it might have a similar concept as the `OnPostConfirmationAsync` method as described in the [documentation for persisting claims from external authentication providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2#map-user-data-keys-and-create-claims). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct. you can implement OnPostConfirmationAsync  in your application . and it will be called once after successful sign-in.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT Thanks. Although the `OnPostConfirmationAsync` is for the  MVC Razor implementation which is called in the final step of external auth for server-generated pages. Just to confirm that for an SPA application I instead would need to call an endpoint on my server similar to that method where I process the JWT myself to create records in the DB? There would be no automatic way to achieve this step as the authentication is all done externally.

Comment: I thought ,you are using MVC razor only  as i saw a controller implementation . Yes in that case you have to create a endpoint.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT Oops the controller implementation was to illustrate an API resource that the SPA app consumes where both API and SPA are authenticated with Azure AD using JWT. Thank you for your clarifying remarks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188402/discussion-between-david-yee-and-mohitverma-msft).

Comment: Do you have any more insights on this @DavidYee ?

Comment: I take it this discussion just died then? No way to implement this?